# Why MS Store package not load .pdb for logging stack trace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, package, store

I need log stack trace in my app package. If I just run .exe file with corresponding .pdb files stack trace logging normal. But if I create Package for Store and install it (or run via VisualStudio) it seems like .pdb not load and stack trace logged without functions name, line ...

What's happening?

PS: In my simple app i use .dll that can throw exception. For stack trace using boost.

[my.dll]

```
void baz() {
    throw CustomException("I am from DLL");
}

void bar() {
    baz();
}

void foo() {
    bar();
}

int add(int a, int b) {
    foo();
    return a + b;
}
```

[consoleApp.exe]

```
int main()
{
    try {
        int res = add(3, 6);
    }
    catch (CustomException& ex) {
        std::cout << "stack trace in dll: \n";

        for (auto& frame : ex.GetStackTrace()) {
            std::cout << frame << std::endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If i deploy package for debugging (with included .pdb) and just run consoleApp.exe in AppX folder stack trace logging with function names and lines:

```
...
CustomException::CustomException(...) in mainDLL.cpp:12
baz(...) in mainDLL.cpp:103
bar(...) in mainDLL.cpp:110
foo(...) in mainDLL.cpp:124
add(...) in mainDLL.cpp:133
...
```

If run package - output smth like:

```
...
CustomException::CustomException(...) in my.dll
CustomException::CustomException(...) in my.dll
CustomException::CustomException(...) in my.dll
...
```

Comment: Hi, how to reproduce your problem? Is this problem related to code? Or is it just some configuration issue?

Comment: Hi. I think that the problem is not related to the code. To reproduce the problem, it is enough to create a c++ simple project and c++ dll that the project uses. Then wrap it into package project via visual studio. After you create .appx or .msix (.pdb files not included there by default so force include them as I wrote above). Now build, deploy and try run just .exe and try run whole package. You will see that package doesn't load .pdb sybmols or somthing else ... PS: I edit orig post to be more clear.